# Extracting week number from POSIXt in R

Tags: r

I have a simple question. What I am trying to do is extract the week number in my set of POSIXt dates in R. Suppose I have the following data

```
set.seed(123)
tseq <- Sys.time() + cumsum(runif(1000)*86400)
min(tseq)
> [1] "2015-05-25 02:09:24 PDT"
```

I want to make sure that the min value in this set of dates is 0 and all other days after this are numbered by week according to this min value. We need to consider the fact that the min date may be in one year and the max date could be in the another year.

**Note:In my example I have constant intervals between dates, but in my actual data the dates are random.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it -- just turn to `POSIXlt` and extract the 'yearday' which, when divided by 7, gives the weeknumber:

```
R> now <- Sys.time() 
R> tseq <- seq(now, length.out = 100, by = "days") 
R> weeknum <- as.POSIXlt(tseq)$yday/7
R> head(weeknum)
[1] 20.4286 20.5714 20.7143 20.8571 21.0000 21.1429
R>
```

You could round or truncate to integer, and figure out how to deal with the first incomplete week versus the first complete week etc.

With *now* as the baseline:

```
R> head(weeknum - weeknum[1], 10)
 [1] 0.000000 0.142857 0.285714 0.428571 0.571429 0.714286 0.857143 \
     1.000000 1.142857 1.285714
R> head(round(weeknum - weeknum[1]), 10)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
R> head(trunc(weeknum - weeknum[1]), 10)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
R>
```

Here is is for an 'random' date sequence:

```
R> tseq <- Sys.time() + cumsum(runif(30)*86400)
R> weeknum <- as.POSIXlt(tseq)$yday/7
R> head(round(weeknum - weeknum[1]), 15)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
R> head(trunc(weeknum - weeknum[1]), 15)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
R>
```

where

```
R> head(difftime(tseq, Sys.time()))
Time differences in hours
[1]  6.08194 17.17697 39.73732 63.21475 66.03445 77.43438
R>
```

*Next Edit:*

Here is a variant of your reformulated question:

```
set.seed(123)
tseq <- Sys.time() + cumsum(runif(10)*86400*2)
as.Date(tseq[1:4])
weeknum <- as.POSIXlt(tseq)$yday/7
head(round(weeknum - weeknum[1]), 10)
head(trunc(weeknum - weeknum[1]), 10)
```

for which I get:

```
R> set.seed(123)
R> tseq <- Sys.time() + cumsum(runif(10)*86400*2)
R> as.Date(tseq[1:4])
[1] "2015-05-25" "2015-05-27" "2015-05-28" "2015-05-29"
R> weeknum <- as.POSIXlt(tseq)$yday/7
R> head(round(weeknum - weeknum[1]), 10)
 [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
R> head(trunc(weeknum - weeknum[1]), 10)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
R>
```

Comment: This doesn't align with what OP requested though - `now would be considered 0`

Comment: `trunc(round(difftime(tseq,now,units="days"))/7)` or something similar should do it too.

Comment: And your `difftime()` comment above is idiomatic too. I think I use that in other answers around here too...

Comment: Will this work even if there are irregular time intervals between each date?

Comment: This doesn't work correctly. I am getting negative numbers. I am editing the question so its more clear.

Comment: It is not rocket science. Try it with vectors of size five or ten, then generalize. Attack it one statement at a time.  There are dozens of questions like this here...